# show compound drawable to EditText on event

Tags: android, android-edittext, compound-drawables

In my application in Activity I want to set `EditText` as I click inside(focus) EditText and type a key clear `button` **should appear on right side** of `EditText` 
 and when EditText is empty that clear button have to removed.
But it is not showing to me..
Which event should I have to implement here..?`onTouch` or `onFocusChange` or `addTextChangedListener` and also what code be there..? following code I have done in activity...

in Activity :

```
 clear = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.round_clear);
     clear.setBounds(0, 0, clear.getIntrinsicWidth(), clear.getIntrinsicHeight());
```

and event  as

```
@Override
public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) 
{
    switch (v.getId()) 
    {
        case R.id.uIDEditText:
                if(hasFocus && !uIDEditText.getText().toString().isEmpty())
                     uIDEditText.setCompoundDrawables(null, null, clear, null);                 
                else
                     uIDEditText.setCompoundDrawables(null, null, null, null);
            break;

        case R.id.pwdEditText:
                if(hasFocus && !pwdEditText.getText().toString().isEmpty())
                    pwdEditText.setCompoundDrawables(null, null, clear, null);
                else
                    pwdEditText.setCompoundDrawables(null, null, null, null);

            break;          
    }               
}
```

another event is :

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) 
{
    switch (v.getId()) 
    {
        case R.id.uIDEditText:
            final int x = (int)event.getX();
            final int y = (int)event.getY();              
            if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP && clear!=null) {
                Rect rBounds = clear.getBounds();

                int n1 = v.getRight();
                int n2 = v.getRight()+rBounds.width();
                int n3 = v.getPaddingTop();
                int n4 = v.getHeight()-v.getPaddingBottom();

                if(x>=(n1) && x<=(n2) && y>=n3 && y<=(n4))
                {
                    uIDEditText.setText("");
                    event.setAction(MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL);
                }
            }
    break;
       }
     }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I sovled it...created following code

```
public class CustomEditText extends EditText {

private Drawable  dRight;
private Rect rBounds;
CustomEditText(Context context,AttributeSet attributeSet){
    super(context,attributeSet);
}
@Override
public void setCompoundDrawables(Drawable left, Drawable top,
        Drawable right, Drawable bottom) {
    /*if (left != null) {
        dLeft = left;
    }*/
    if (right != null) {
        dRight = right;
    }
    super.setCompoundDrawables(left, top, right, bottom);
}

@Override
public void addTextChangedListener(TextWatcher watcher) {       
    super.addTextChangedListener(watcher);      
}

@Override
protected void onTextChanged(CharSequence text, int start,
        int lengthBefore, int lengthAfter) {        
    super.onTextChanged(text, start, lengthBefore, lengthAfter);
    if(this.getText().toString().length()>0)
        this.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(null, null, dRight, null);
    else
        this.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(null, null, null, null);
}   
@Override
protected void finalize() throws Throwable {
    dRight = null;
    rBounds = null;
    super.finalize();
}
 }
```

and added in xml:

```
<com.example.screen.CustomEditText
    android:id="@+id/uIDEditText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"       
    android:drawableRight="@drawable/round_clear"       
    android:textColor="#ffffff" />
```

in Activity (edittext ontouch listener):

```
 uIDEditText.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {         
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() != MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)                         
                return false;

            if (event.getX() > uIDEditText.getWidth()  - clear.getIntrinsicWidth()) 
            {
                uIDEditText.setText("");    
                event.setAction(MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL);
            }
            return false;   
        }
    });
```

Comment: @Rajesh clear is Drawable variable, you have to identify it in OnCreate(). Here `drawable/round_clear"`

Answer (score 0):

What you want is here .

Use Textwatcher functionality for edittext.

```
package com.example.editwatch;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {


    EditText edittext_search;
    ImageView imageView1;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        edittext_search=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        imageView1=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

        edittext_search.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                if(edittext_search.getText().length()>0)
                {
                    imageView1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
                else
                {
                    imageView1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });


    }

}
```

Comment: for imageview it works that i know but it not working for `compound drawables` inside `EditText`..(thks for suggession)